# Invoking javascript built-in objects constructor using call and apply

Tags: javascript

I am trying to invoke date object constructor on a click event using call/apply, but the constructor is not giving me the output. Here is the code snippet:

```
function invokeCommand(cmd) {
    var parts='';
    return cmd.call(this, parts);
}

YUI().use('node','event-base', function (Y) {
    Y.on('domready', function () {
        Y.one('#myconsole').on('submit', function () {
            var cmd = Y.one('#cmd_input').get('value');
            alert(invokeCommand(cmd));
        });
    });
});
```

Here I am trying to invoke the constructor and get the output or return the definition. Any thoughts?

I replaced the cmd.call with Date.call and I can able to see the output, but when Date is store in cmd var and invoked its not giving the output,

```
function invokeCommand(cmd) {
    var parts='';
    //return cmd.call(null);
    return Date.call(null);
}

YUI().use('node','event-base', function (Y) {
    Y.on('domready', function () {
        Y.one('#jsconsole').on('submit', function () {
            var cmd = Y.one('#cmd_input').get('value');
        alert(invokeCommand(cmd));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I do not think 'this' means what you think it means in your invokeCommand. At that moment it refers to the global window object.

Comment: What are the changes I need to do to the above code?

Comment: Besides, `call()` is a method of the `Function` type, and you're calling it in a string. Aren't you getting errors in the console?

Comment: Hmm... thats the problem am not observing any errors in the console :(